# DateField: Where to find the Source of the setValue function

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Where can I find the sourcecode of the setValue function of the DateField? I mean there must happen something in it cause my store saves a Date object (at least I think so) and the DateField takes the format in account when I set it...

I need to build a Displayed field for dates that's why I am looking at this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in the source is just a Documentation override for the API, no more no less.

The `Ext.form.field.DateField` extend `Ext.form.field.Picker` which inherits `setValue` itself from `Ext.form.field.Text` which overrides and calls the `setValue` method of the `Ext.form.field.Base` which it has extended.

`Ext.form.field.Base` itself calls `setRawValue` with a `valueToRaw` call as argument which get **[overriden](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-method-valueToRaw)** in `Ext.form.field.DateField`. There you are...

Answer (score 0):

It's available in their api. Next to each method there is a view source button that takes you right into the code.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/source/Date4.html#Ext-form-field-Date-method-setValue

Comment: If you had looked at the linked you posted you should have notice that there is no code for this method, just the comments! -1